# Alternative data providers

Tags: data

What data vendors/providers have you come across or used for alternative datasets? Not talking about market data here. Things like rainfall, coronavirus stats, new car production in China etc. I

Answer (score 2):

There is a website called [AlternativeData](https://alternativedata.org/data-providers/) that have aggregated data vendors for alternative datasets (eg. weather data, mobile phone location data, satellite data, and much more). Often, specific datasets come with a (hefty) price. You can try and look around and see if you find something interesting. Personally, I don't know any free alternative data providers. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking around Datarade.ai. It's technically an online catalogue for all sorts of data covering a range of categories including Geospatial, Environmental, Web, Healthcare and etc